# Prevent colorscheme from changing background color

Tags: neovim, linux-arch

I've got a sick terminal colorscheme, and i'm using vim-one colorscheme for neovim, what i'd like to do is stop it from changing the background color (since i like my terminals background color more)

i don't have my terminals background color i was hoping i could just make neovim not change it. i can find it if need be but i'd rather neovim just does not change it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the background is changing, then the colorscheme is changing it.  You can either choose a colorscheme that doesn't do that, or try overriding the colorscheme.

```
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight Normal ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE
```

The colorscheme may be designed around a particular background color, though, and there may be other highlight groups which need adjustment.

Comment: bg=NONE caused an error for me, i removed it now it works fine, thanks!